# Using ISO-690 / AFNOR Z 44-005 standard in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, zotero, iso

I'm using Zotero and when I'm exporting the whole collection I can choose the right format, BibTeX here, but when I cite in References it do not follow the ISO-690 standard.
Should I use a custom .bib or something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bib file is independent of the bibliography style you want to use. If you are okay with using biblatex, there is a package [biblatex-iso690](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690) that implements the standard.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=iso-alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{sigfridsson}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh ok so I only need to change the style, nice thanks a lot, a last thing, why is this different from citations of Zotero as shown here (especially the date) : `WANG, Xintao, YU, Ke, WU, Shixiang, GU, Jinjin, LIU, Yihao, DONG, Chao, QIAO, Yu et LOY,Chen  Change,  2019.   ESRGAN:  Enhanced  Super-Resolution  Generative  Adversarial  Networks:Munich, Germany, September 8-14, 2018, Proceedings, Part V. In :  .  pp. 63-79.  ISBN 978-3-030-11020-8.`

Comment: @AngeloSantarossa Can you add that the .bib format of that reference to your question?

Comment: Maybe just write something like this : [style=iso-authoryear] ?

Comment: @AngeloSantarossa the bib file is wrong. The title sould be "ESRGAN: Enhanced Super-Resolution Generative Adversarial Networks". If you cite it as a journal article, the place should be "Cham" and the publisher "Springer International Publishing". For the location of a conference, biblatex has the field "venue", where you can put "Munich, Germany". You should use the publication date of the journal issue and remove the date from the title. You can download the bib file for the article from Springer: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-11021-5, click "cite paper" on the right.

Comment: @AngeloSantarossa biblatex-iso690 has different styles (iso-authoryear, iso-numeric, iso-alphabetic, iso-authortitle). Refer to the manual p. 3 for details. choose whatever you like. As far as I know, the only change the way references are printed ([1], [Wan+19], etc) and not the formatting in the bibliography.

Comment: Ok thanks everything is clear now, thanks again for your time !